# Hide a line on plotly line graph

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Imagine I have lines A, B, C, D, and E.  I want lines A, B, and C to appear on the plotly line chart.  I want the user to have the option to add lines D and E but D and E should be hidden by default.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Example, how would I hide Australia by default.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')
fig.show()
```

Comment: you need provide the code you have so far

Comment: Updated to include example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to play with the parameter `visible` setting it as `legendonly` within every trace

```py
import plotly.express as px
countries_to_hide = ["Australia"]
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')

fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(visible="legendonly") 
                   if trace.name in countries_to_hide else ())
fig.show()
```

[image]